# regular expr in matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

I am using the [regexpdir](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16216-regexpdir) tool to select files in a directory. I works for simple file suffixes as show on the example using the expression '^.*.tif$'. But now I want to search for the ending `- DicNr1_ORG.tif` and tried it with

```
^.*\. - DicNr1_ORG.tif$
```

The whole code is then

```
regexpdir(objEntry.('dir'), '^.*\. - DicNr1_ORG.tif$', false)
```

But then the result is an empty list.

How would the correct regexp look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'^.* - DicNr1_ORG\.tif$'
```

or just

```
' - DicNr1_ORG\.tif$'
```